# How to change checkbox label in Excel using Lotus Script?

Tags: excel, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

i am having requirement to add checkbox in excel column dynamically .i have added using the below code generated by macro. But i not allowing me to check the label of that generated checkbox please help me out from the below issue....

Code to generate the dynamic checkbox

```
xlSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(660, chkheight, 72, 72).Select
```

when i am try to change checkbox label using below code. it creating problem.

```
Selection.Characters.Text = "TEST"
```

Please anyone help out.Thanks in Advance

Comment: It appears this question has been improperly tagged. LotusScript and XPages are both related to IBM Domino, but other than that, have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
xlSheet.Selection.Characters.Text = "TEST"
```